# Is this a correct usage of v-on:change?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a text input that has a `v-model` and a `v-on:change` attached to it. As the user types I update an array in `data` and the UI is bound to that array. I also want to call a method to send the user input via AJAX. The data sent to the server is the result of a computed property.

```
<div id="app">
  <input
      id="user-input"
      type="text"
      v-model="userInput"
      v-on:change="process()">

   <ul id="parsed-list">
      <li v-for="item in parsedInput">
          {{ item }}
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>

let parse = input => {
    return input.split(',')
}

let serverProcess = values => {
    // Send array to server
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    userInput: ''
  },
  computed: {
    parsedInput () {
        return parse(this.userInput)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    process () {
        serverProcess(this.parsedInput);
    }
  }
});
```

Is this usage of both a `v-model` and `v-on:change` together best practice Vue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recommend using a watch instead of a `v-on:change`. In the view, you would remove the `v-on:change`. Any time `parsedInput` changes (due to userInput changing), then the watch function will be called. It is important that the watch function be named the same as the computed/data property.

```
new Vue({
    computed: {
        parsedInput () {
            return parse(this.userInput)
        }
    }
    methods: {
        process () {
            serverProcess(this.parsedInput);
        }
    },
    watch: {
        parsedInput() {
            this.process()
        }
    }
})
```

You can read more about watches here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

IMO, this is better because you are describing more of the behavior of the application through code rather than the view. This would make your component more testable. It also has the effect that if `parsedInput` or `userInput` changed for some other reason other than through v-model, then the watch would be called.

Answer (score 8):

*thumbs up* @kmc0590000.
In addition, with `watch` you can also see the previous state and current. They are passed as parameters.

**v-model** is just syntactic sugar and does the following:

```
<input :value="userInput" @input="change">
```

You can also write `@change` instead of `v-on:` and `:value` instead of `v-bind:value`.

In Line 6 (`v-on:change="process()"`) you can remove the parentheses. The input event is given to your method as parameter and you can access the attributes directly. (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers)